# Split text string delimited by comma and line break / carriage return

Tags: vba, excel, csv, parsing

I have scoured every forum available. I'm struggling. I'm pulling dynamic reports using REST api calls and I'm getting a response text that has every entry double quotes and comma delimited and every row with a line break.

E.g. -

```
"Employee ID","Name","Hours"
"123","John Doe","8:00"
```

I can't do a replace command because some attributes will have commas or double quotes inevitably.

Current method is to SPLIT into an array with the delimiters as "," but the best I can get looks like this still!

```
"Employee ID Name        Hours"
"123                John Doe  8:00  "
```

Basically the inbetween delimiters are taken care of but I am left with the leading and trailing double quotes on every row.

Comment: Then first remove them by `=MID(YourString,2,Len(YourString)-2)` then do your split on the `","`

Comment: That solves the first and last ones, but not the line break start and end quotes

Comment: Then replace all Chr(10) and Chr(13) with a `,` then it will be split on the `","`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This replaces delimiters (",") with tab characters and splits out lines

It's hard to know exactly what you want from output but at least now you should be able to manipulate the lines and data fields anyway you want.

```
sub ConvertData(strData as string)    
    Dim varLines    As Variant
    Dim strLine     As String
    Dim lngCounter  As Long
    Dim intField    As Integer

    strData = """Employee ID"",""Name"",""Hours""" & vbCrLf & """123"",""John Doe"",""8:00"""

    ' Retrieve each line
    varLines = Split(strData, vbCrLf)
    For lngCounter = LBound(varLines) To UBound(varLines)

        strLine = CStr(varLines(lngCounter))
Debug.Print "Original Line: " & strLine

        strLine = Replace(strLine, """,""", vbTab)

Debug.Print "After removing delimiters: " & strLine

        strLine = Mid(strLine, 2, Len(strLine) - 2)
Debug.Print "After removing end quotes: " & strLine

    Next lngCounter
end sub
```

This is what Debug prints out (there's a tab between each field)

```
Original Line: "Employee ID","Name","Hours"
After removing delimiters: "Employee ID Name    Hours"
After removing end quotes: Employee ID  Name    Hours
Original Line: "123","John Doe","8:00"
After removing delimiters: "123 John Doe    8:00"
After removing end quotes: 123  John Doe    8:00
```

Comment: I do need to keep the rows, I'm doing two splits, 1 for rows (ch13) and one for commas (chr10)

Comment: Thats carriage return / line feed characters - comma is 44. What exactly do you want your output example lines to look at then? Your title says "Split text string delimited by comma and line break / carriage return" - do you want to leave the double quotes around items?

Comment: I want to remove all double quotes! :)

Comment: updated code sample (including @Scott Craner's suggestion)

Comment: Then upvote @Scott Craner's comment in your original post

Answer (score 0):

```
'Split csv
SplitCSVReport = Split(CSVReport, Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
For i = LBound(SplitCSVReport) To UBound(SplitCSVReport)
    CSVSplit = Split(SplitCSVReport(i), Chr(34) & ",")
        For v = LBound(CSVSplit) To UBound(CSVSplit)
        With Cells(15, 15)
            Range(.Offset(i, v), .Offset(i, v)) = Mid(CSVSplit(v), 2, Len(CSVSplit(v)))
            End With
        Next v
Next i
```